# Why only three combinations of three 1s-orbitals?

Tags: atoms, orbitals

When bringing three $\mathrm{H}$-atoms close together, their 1s-orbitals will overlab and combine. I have a text saying that there are 3 ways to combine these. Those three combinations are:

[image]

for orbital A, B and C. Why are there only these three combinations? What about $$\psi=\psi(A)-\psi(B)-\psi(C)$$ for example?

Comment: Because there are just three orbitals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the wavefunction you have chosen is simply a linear combination of the others.

Now why these choices, You have to study what is called degenerate perturbation theory to understand that.

What happens when you bring multiple hydrogen atoms  together? The solution to Hamiltonian of the free hydrogen atom is no longer exactly correct, it would acquire corrections, due to perturbations, Now if you study the perturbed operator you can infer what "Selected" eigen wavefunctions are.